# VMSS for outgoing connections in Azure

Tags: azure, load-balancing, nat, azure-vm-scale-set

I probably need outgoing proxy or something similar in Azure to have the flexibility of vmss to scale-in my stateless app by changing the number of instances (autoscaling) and use a single public IP address with no limitations on number of IP connections (that is the case for basic and standard load balancer). How can I attache a nat device to a vmss in azure? Probably that is the wrong question. What is the right questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use an Azure load balancer as a proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections) for outbound internet connectivity by using source network address translation (SNAT). See how to [deploy VMSS with existing LB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/configure-vm-scale-set-powershell) and [outbound rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/outbound-rules) and [guidelines should be considered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-virtual-machine-scale-sets). If the backend VMSS don't have instance-level public IP (ILPIP) addresses, they establish outbound connectivity via the **frontend IP** of the public load balancer.

If you are facing some issues, see [how to throughout the outbound connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/troubleshoot-outbound-connection).

Comment: all those things are done, azure's lb has limitations on ip connections, and I don't really need a load balancer, I need a snat gateway. And I don't need public ips on all the machines in the scale set.

Comment: You could configure a virtual network subnet to use a NAT gateway, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway-resource) and this [step-by-step guide](https://www.rebeladmin.com/2020/05/step-step-guide-source-network-address-translation-snat-subnet-using-azure-nat-gateway-powershell-guide/#:~:text=In%20Azure%2C%20we%20can%20do,Gateway%20has%20the%20following%20characteristics%2C&text=One%20public%20IP%20can%20provide,concurrent%20UDP%20and%20TCP%20flows.) with PowerShell.

Comment: How can I change the PAT settings for the load balancer?

Comment: I have not validated it yet but it looks like to use [Set-AzLoadBalancerOutboundRuleConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/set-azloadbalanceroutboundruleconfig?view=azps-5.0.0) with `-AllocatedOutboundPort `.